# def __str__(self) return doesnt work - python 3.6/ Django 1.11.6

Tags: python, django

[Screenshot of My Admin section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjAiZ.jpg)The following is my code in the models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class RestaurantLocation(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Instead of returning the restaurant name, it returns "RestaurantLocation object" in the output window of the admin section.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: confusion between `__repr__` and `__str__` perhaps?

Comment: @AnthonySottile: looks like it.  @alphageek: try using `print(RestaurantLocation)`.  It will probably return what you are looking for.  If you are just passing the `RestaurantLocation` object, you will get the `__repr__` back, not the `__str__`

Comment: Please check the screenshot of my admin section that I have uploaded.

Comment: `return '%s' % self.name`

Comment: Also, are you _sure_ that the definition of `__str__` is properly indented underneath the class definition?

Comment: The code you have posted looks fine, and would work. There must be something you are doing differently locally...

Comment: @alphageek please show your admin.py code of the particular module

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem.

I just made alignment correct.

```html
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

or

```html
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name
```

NOTE:: def should start exactly below of description, a little bit of spacing will cause indention error.

you will get something like this error.

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

It might be helpful to someone.

Comment: is there a way to return name and category? like:

return '%s %s' % self.name, self.category